# How to make a photo (still image) move in flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, animation

I work for an artist and I need to make a website similar to [this](http://www.thelotuseater.com)

Instead of that picture frame though I have a photo (in jpeg) of a painting of the artist. The painting has a tree which needs to be slowly revealed/drawn and then have its branches and leef move constantly.

It sounds to me like this can be done in flash but I have never worked in flash before so I dont really know how to do this!

Is that possible? And if so is flash the way to go or is there an easier/better way?

Are there any good tutorials for this task anywhere?

Thanks in advance

Mike

Comment: Far too broad a question. You're asking "how do I program in Flash", for which the answer can only be "just do it".

Comment: @Marc B Maybe I didn't put it well...I'm just wondering if you can somehow "convert" the image in to a primitive or something that you can manipulate in flash or if I have to model/draw the whole thing on top of it or whatever works..Just point to the right direction :)

Comment: Flash does have bitmap tracing functionality to produce vectors that you can animate, but I don't find it to be very accurate, and it creates lots of points in your vector that will add to the file size and can affect the smoothness of your animations.  It is probably better to draw the objects as vectors yourself, you can get much more accurate and usable results by hand.

Comment: @shanethehat I see...Pff..I was kinda hoping to avoid that but I suppose I can't! :p Thanks for the reply!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't about programming, it's about animating, so it's off-topic here. In the meantime though I know how to animate that so I'll give you an overview.

In Flash you can import jpg or png images so that's easy enough. Then you can put the imported image into a symbol (probably a MovieClip) in order to rotate and scale it in the animation. That particular animation of the image growing is done using a Mask layer on top of the imported bitmap.

Comment: Yeah I just found a tutorial on youtube about this! Do you by any chance know how should I go about animating the branches and leaves? I need to give a more realistic look..like if the wind moves them!

Comment: Split the image into pieces before you import them. That way you can move each piece individually.

Answer (score 1):

Just look closer at those moving images - they're split into transparent layers, moving with different speeds. Sometimes they're flashing - that may be semitransparent layer changing alpha, with BlendMode.ADD or something. You can do a lot of effects with clever layering.